# How do I update the items async in a b-table from Bootstrap-Vue reusing the items provider function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap-Vue v2.0.0-rc.11 and I just cannot get my head around how to update the table content. I am sure it is trivial.

I am pulling my content from a backend using an item provider function.

```
        <b-table
                 :items="myProvider"
        >
```

The initial call works just fine with the following method.

```
export default {
    methods: {
        myProvider(ctx) {
            let promise = axios.get('/backend?currentPage=' + ctx.currentPage);

            return promise.then((response) => {
                return(response.items || []);
            });
        },
```

To duplicate a row item I open a modal to enter a new name. I make a backend call for the duplication which works well. Now I want to refresh the content displayed in the table showing the new item. How do I do this?

The easiest I can think of would be to call the item provider function (here: 'myProvider') again. I can do this from the modal but I cannot provide the correct parameter (here: 'ctx').

Is there an event to trigger/emit to reissue the backend call?

I tried things like :

```
this.$refs.nameOfTable.$forceUpdate()

this.$refs.nameOfTable.$emit('XXX') // XXX = placeholder for various events
```

Any hint is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's hidden in the docs, but it's just a simple refresh() call on the table reference.

```
<b-table ref="table" ... ></b-table>
this.$refs.table.refresh();
```

From the **Force refreshing of table data** section of [the docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#force-refreshing-of-table-data).

Comment: `this.$refs` is undefined

Comment: @BuddyZ
the scope in an asynchronous call is different and therefore you don't have direct access to `this`. You can bind it like
```javascript
fetch("url")
.then(function(data) {
// your code
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarol. I had no idea why this.$refs would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

refresh is not worked now

you can use 'key' attribute instead.

```
<b-table key="key" ... ></b-table>

data() {
  return {
    key: 1
  }

this.key += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also trigger the refresh of the provider function by emitting the event refresh::table on $root with the single argument being the id of your b-table. You must have a unique ID on your table for this to work.

```
this.$root.$emit('bv::refresh::table', 'my-table')
```

Or by calling the refresh() method on the table reference:

```
this.$refs.table.refresh()
```

Link to documentation:https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#force-refreshing-of-table-data